# Column sum (displayed in page footer) not working on first page. But working on second page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working on a jasper report. My requirement is to show the running total for debit and credit column which I'm getting from java as JRBeanCollectionDataSource. I have created a variable and set the resetType="Page" and calculation as Sum. The total on first page is always zero where as the total on second page is correct.

My field is within subDataset. I'm returning the sum of debit and credit values from datasetRun.

Subdataset:

```
<subDataset name="TransactionDataSet" uuid="1c386547-d313-475c-b023-9f1b6f198535">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="accountTypeName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="accountNum" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="transactionText" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="currencyCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="amountDebited" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <field name="amountCredited" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <field name="regionId" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="departmentId" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="costCenterId" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <variable name="debitSumForPage" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amountDebited}]]></variableExpression>
            <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO]]></initialValueExpression>
        </variable>
        <variable name="creditSumForPage" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amountCredited}]]></variableExpression>
            <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO]]></initialValueExpression>
        </variable>
</subDataset>
```

Global variable:

```
<variable name="totalDebitForPage" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="totalCreditForPage" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

return code:

```
<datasetRun subDataset="TransactionDataSet" uuid="c6dc230d-6e84-4618-b973-c5cedc63dcaf">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{TransactionDatasource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <returnValue fromVariable="debitSumForPage" toVariable="totalDebitForPage"/>
                        <returnValue fromVariable="creditSumForPage" toVariable="totalCreditForPage"/>
</datasetRun>
```

I need to get the page total on all pages.

Comment: Try to set calculation="System" for the totalDebitForPage and totalCreditForPage variables, and add calculation="Sum" in <returnValue ..>

Comment: Tried it. Same result. totalDebitForPage and totalCreditForPage are correct only on the last page(regardless of 2 or more pages). From first till last-1 pages the value is 0. Added resetType="Page" for these two fields. Still not working